# Is it better to have a smaller amount of code but less clear, or more code and more clear?

Tags: performance

I've been working on this project for quite some time and it has gotten to be about 2000 lines long. It was done in such a way that it just worked, but would be an absolute nightmare for someone to read (apart from me). So I set out to modularise the code and make it generally easier to understand, In doing so it is now nearly 3000 lines!

It accomplishes the same goal in the end, but I made the flow of operations more intuitive and in a easier to modify (you would struggle to alter anything and have it still work in the previous version).

So my question is this: Which is better? I often here people say if you can do the same thing in less lines then it tends to be better, but the programmer friendly aspect of it is important as well.

I might actually see if the smaller one runs faster or not by timing them, that might be interesting. I'm pretty sure the second version is bigger because of the new design, not just added white-space.

Comment: More code, easier to read will always win in my book.  Imagine how many bugs will be introduced when either you or someone else has to pick up this code 3-6 months from now when everything is forgotten.

Comment: Make it readable. More or less code is irrevelant for me (you can have a lot of code and still have it hard to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

When performance matters, some obscure code may be required.

Otherwise, more understandable code is better, especially when working with other people. After all, code is read much more often than it is written.

Answer (score 1):

More code and more clear. Clarity should always come first. Code has a twofold function, for a machine to execute it and for humans to read and understand it. The former is nearly useless without the latter.

Answer (score 0):

undoubtedly, the code should be fairly easy to read not to hamper when you make future changes

Answer (score 0):

For any compiled language, things like comments, whitespace and variable names don't matter in the end, so use those as a good tool to promote clarity. For bits of code that you think will run faster but look more confusing, use this to your advantage.

Also consider how many times the piece of code is being passed over in run time, and if it's a lot, how much extra time the new code structure will take. In most cases, the computer will actually run the same amount of operations for two different structures of code, for example:

```
// Code Snippet 1...
foo = (bar == true) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

// Code Snippet 2...
if(bar == true) {
  foo = 'Yes';
} else {
  foo = 'No';
}
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Clarity is important so people can validate and/or modify the code correctly, but that doesn't necessarily mean "more" code.
My feeling is that often less code is clearer.
Regardless, the comments should be clear and to-the-point, not blathering on and being ignored.